# Embedded wxWidgets for ThreadX OS

Tags: user-interface, embedded, wxwidgets, greenhills, threadx

I'm working on an embedded system using ThreadX.  The project will involve a GUI.

I'm looking for a port of wxWidgets for embedded on ThreadX operating system.

My search has turned up wxWidgets for embedded Linux and WinCE.

Also, is wxWidgets difficult to port to a new (different) OS?

Thanks,

(The project tools are C++ using *Greenhills* compiler and *ThreadX* operating system with *ARM9* processor and conservative amount of RAM and FLASH.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no wxWidgets port to ThreadX. And while porting wx to a new OS is usually not a problem at all, porting it to a different GUI toolkit is quite a lot of work. I don't know anything about GUI in this OS but basically you have the choice between wrapping native GUI widgets in wx API (supposing that the platform does have some native GUI) or implement just a small subset of graphical primitives natively and use wxWidgets own widgets implemented in wx itself (so called wxUniversal port). The latter is usually less work and as it's needed to do the former anyhow, this is what we usually advise people to do first anyhow. But wrapping native widgets (again, if any -- some embedded platforms don't have any native GUI at all) results in more native look-and-feel, of course.

In any case, you shouldn't expect this to be trivial to do, creating a new port will require some effort although usually you can reduce it if your application needs just a subset of wx GUI functionality in the first place. The only simple solution is to make X/DirectFB/GTK+ work on your platform and use the corresponding existing wx port but this might be unacceptable because of extra resources consumption due to the use of another toolkit.

Finally, if you do intend to port wxWidgets to a new platform, wx-dev mailing list would be the right place to ask for help and advice.

Comment: Looks like a solution is to port wxUniversal configuration to the ThreadX platform.  This would allow switching between the wxMSW version and ThreadX with least amount of changes.  Still a viable solution for a desktop emulation of the embedded system.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a strong reason not to use Express Logic's own [PEGX GUI library](http://www.rtos.com/page/product.php?id=5)?

Comment: Support {lack of} from Swell Software and Express Logic.  I would like to have a version that runs on Windows also.  IOW, I want build the code for Windows platform that runs similar to the embedded platform.  This makes debugging easier.

Comment: Given that the PEGX demo runs on Windows, this seems possible.  However lack of support may still be an issue.